# Token based authentication in ASP.NET Web API 2 not working

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var myProvider = new MyAuthorizationServerProvider();
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = myProvider
        };
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions());
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    }
}
```

Token generate successfully but when I use this token to access Authorize controller that not work properly. Always response message show "Authorization has been denied for this request"
[Here postman send request for generate token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XXRK.png)

This is my MyAuthorizationServerProvider class

```
 public class MyAuthorizationServerProvider: OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        if(context.UserName== "admin" && context.Password == "admin")
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "admin"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Admin Ahasanul Banna"));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else if (context.UserName=="user" && context.Password=="user")
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "user"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "User Ahasanul Banna"));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("Invalid_grant", "Provided username & password is incorrect");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And my AuthorizeAttribute class

```
    public class AuthorizeAttribute :System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        }
        else
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }

    }
}
```

When I access any Authorize action using this token server response "Authorization has been denied for this request." message[Here Postman send request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLsfY.png)

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("authenticate")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetForAuthenticate()
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        return Ok("Hello" + identity.Name);
    }
    [Authorize(Roles ="admin")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("authorize")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetForAdmin()
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        var roles = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Select(c => c.Value);

        return Ok("Hello" + identity.Name +" Role: " +string.Join(",",roles.ToList()));
    }
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Check this code

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    var myProvider = new MyAuthorizationServerProvider();
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
        Provider = myProvider
    };
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions());
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
}
```

here you use an authorization server with configured options (OK):

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
```

then override it without options (NOT OK)

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions());
```

Just remove the second `app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer` and try again.

Also you forgot to add

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

Comment: Add `app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());` after `app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer`

Comment: Glad to have been of help